# Would the paranormal activity also have occurred without finding the camera?

Tags: plot-explanation, paranormal-activity-6

#### SPOILERS AHEAD

In Paranormal Activity 5 Ghost Dimension, it all started with the modified camera which was found. At the beginning, the ghost was just a small glitch above the light bulbs,  but became bigger and bigger,  until it could interact with matter.

1. Wouldn't all this have happened if nobody found the camera?

   In the movie it is said that the daemon gets stronger, the more fear the victims have. This explains the extreme strength at the end.
2. But at the beginning, nobody was frightened about the glitches seen through the camera (the camera guy was just fascinated and the others were not believing), or am I wrong? If nobody was frightened in the beginning,  I cannot think about an explanation, how the daemon got strong in the beginning.